# Return a string allocated with malloc?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm creating a function that returns a string. The size of the string is known at runtime, so I'm planning to use `malloc()`, but I don't want to give the user the responsibility for calling `free()` after using my function's return value.

How can this be achieved? How do other functions that return strings (`char *`) work (such as `getcwd()`, `_getcwd()`, `GetLastError()`, `SDL_GetError()`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your challenge is that *something* needs to release the resources (i.e. cause the `free()` to happen).

Normally, the caller frees the allocated memory either by calling `free()` directly (see how `strdup` users work for instance), or by calling a function you provide the wraps `free`. You might, for instance, require callers to call a `foo_destroy` function. As another poster points out you *might* choose to wrap that in an opaque `struct`, though that's not *necessary* as having your own allocation and destroy functions is useful even without that (e.g. for resource tracking).

However, another way would be to use some form of clean-up function. For instance, when the string is allocated, you could attach it to a list of resources allocated in a pool, then simply free the pool when done. This is how `apache2` works with its `apr_pool` structure. In general, you don't `free()` anything specifically under that model. See [here](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__pools.html) and (easier to read) [here](http://structure.usc.edu/svn/svn.developer.pools.html).

What you can't do in C (as there is no reference counting of `malloc()`d structures) is directly determine when the last 'reference' to an object goes out of scope and free it then. That's because you don't have references, you have pointers.

Lastly, you asked how existing functions return `char *` variables:

- Some (like `strdup`, `get_current_dir_name` and `getcwd` under some circumstances) expect the caller to free.
- Some (like `strerror_r` and `getcwd` in under other circumstances) expect the caller to pass in a buffer of sufficient size.
- Some do both: from the `getcwd` man page:

> As an extension to the POSIX.1-2001 standard, Linux (libc4, libc5, glibc) `getcwd()` allocates the buffer dynamically
>   using `malloc(3)` if `buf` is `NULL`.  In this case, the allocated buffer has the length `size` unless `size` is zero,  when
>   `buf` is allocated as big as necessary.  The caller should `free(3)` the returned buffer.

- Some use an internal static buffer and are thus not reentrant / threadsafe (yuck - do not do this). See `strerror` and why `strerror_r` was invented.
- Some only return pointers to constants (so reentrancy is fine), and no free is required.
- Some (like `libxml`) require you to use a separate `free` function (`xmlFree()` in this case)
- Some (like `apr_palloc`) rely on the pool technique above.

Comment: I like this answer, +1, thanks! Specially the pool way, that could be a great idea. Do you have any idea about how the functions I mention work? All of them returns a `char*` and there's no need to free it.

Comment: I've updated the above with some examples. `getcwd` depends on the calling convention. My Linux dev machine does not have man pages for the other functions you list but I'm sure the appropriate documentation for the API will exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this ***in C***.  You have to either pass a parameter with size information, so that `malloc()` and `free()` can be called in the called function, or the calling function has to call free after `malloc()`.

Many object oriented languages (eg. C++)  handle memory in such a way as to do what you want to, but not C.

***Edit***

***By size*** information as an argument, I mean something to let the called function know the how many bytes of memory are owned by the pointer you are passing.  This can be done by looking directly at the called string if it has already been assigned a value, such as:

```
char test1[]="this is a test";
char *test2="this is a test";
```

when called like this:

```
readString(test1); // (or test2) 

char * readString(char *abc)
{
    int len = strlen(abc);
    return abc;
}
```

Both of those arguments will result in `len` = 14

***However*** if you create a non populated variable, such as:

```
char *test3;
```

And allocate the same amount of memory, but do not populate it, for example:

```
test3 = malloc(strlen("this is a test") +1);
```

There is no way for the called function to know what memory has been allocated.  The variable `len` will == 0 inside the 1st prototype of `readString()`.  However, if you change the prototype `readString()` to:

```
readString(char *abc, int sizeString);  Then size information as an argument can be used to create memory:    

void readString(char *abc, size_t sizeString)
{
    char *in;
    in = malloc(sizeString +1);

    //do something with it  
    //then free it
    free(in);

}
```

example call:

```
int main()
{
     int len;
     char *test3;

     len =  strlen("this is a test") +1; //allow for '\0'  
     readString(test3, len);
     // more code
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please give an example for "pass a parameter with size information, so the malloc and free can be called in the called funcion"? How that works?

Comment: @cdonts - ***See edit***.   Size information can be derived from the argument itself (an initialized and populated string) or as a separate argument, such as a size_t variable assigned a value representing memory allocated to a variable, but for which variable has not been populated yet. Both are briefly addressed above.

Answer (score 1):

Many libraries force the user to deal with memory allocation.  This is a good idea because every application has its own patterns of object lifetime and reuse.  It's good for the library to make as few assumptions about its users as possible.

Say a user wants to call your library function like this:

```
for (a lot of iterations)
{ 
    params = get_totally_different_params();
    char *str = your_function(params);
    do_something(str);
    // now we're done with this str forever
}
```

If your libary `malloc`s the string every time, it is wasting a lot of effort calling `malloc`, and possibly showing poor cache behavior if `malloc` picks a different block each time.

Depending on the specifics of your library, you might do something like this:

```
int output_size(/*params*/);
void func(/*params*/, char *destination);
```

where `destination` is required to be at least `output_size(params)` size, or you could do something like the socket `recv` API:

```
int func(/*params*/, char *destination, int destination_size);
```

where the return value is:

```
< desination_size: this is the number of bytes we actually used
== destination_size: there may be more bytes waiting to output
```

These patterns both perform well when called repeatedly, because the caller can reuse the same block of memory over and over without any allocations at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in C.

Return a pointer and it is up to the person calling the function to call `free`

Alternatively use C++. `shared_ptr` etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how other functions work? (see the examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a opaque struct.

Give the user access to pointers to your struct but not its internal. Create a function to release resources.

```
void release_resources(struct opaque *ptr);
```

Of course the user needs to call the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to avoid the user to call a release-resources function. See the update please!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the allocated strings and free them in an atexit routine (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atexit.htm).  In the following, I have used a global variable but it could be a simple array or list if you have one handy.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
char* freeme = NULL;
void AStringRelease(void)
{
    if (freeme != NULL)
        free(freeme);
}
char* AStringGet(void)
{
    freeme = malloc(20);
    strcpy(result, "A String");
    atexit(AStringRelease);
    return freeme;
}
```